# Java Migrations not being picked up by Flyway

Tags: java, database-migration, flyway

I am trying to use Flyway to run my database migration scripts. I have two SQL scripts and one Java Script I am trying to run. When I run ./gradlew flywayMigrate or gradle flywayMigrate it only picks up on the SQL scripts and not the Java one.
My project setup is below:

> database_migrations
>   
> --->src
>   
> ------>main/java
>   
> --------->db/migration
>   
> -------------V3__load_data.java
>   
> ------>main/resources
>   
> --------->db/migration
>   
> -------------V1__base_table.sql
>   
> -------------V2__stored_procedures.sql

I have tried a variety of solutions to get the java script to run such as specifying the `flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration` but that just results in this output `Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration`. I have tried moving it other packages. I have tried putting it in a jar and running from the commandline tool but it doesn't pick it up. I have tried both the JDBCMigration and the SpringJDBCMigration class. 
Am I missing something in how it is supposed to be run?

*When I run it with gradlew compileJava in my jenkins instance it throws Could not find tools.jar, not sure if that my be related*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue. I found that the problem was that my java_home was not pointing anywhere. Once I set that my code compiled but the java migrations were still not picked up on. I added the `-Dflyway.locations=classpath:db.migrations` to the end of my gradle statement and it picked it up immediately! Hope this help somebody else in need!